# Make border-top touch the top of the page without moving the text

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am a student and still learning, this is my very first project so please bear with me.

In the nav bar I'm trying to add a hover selector to the links, where it shows a blue bar on top that's supposed to touch the border of the page.

The upper part is how it should be, the bottom part is my attempt at replicating it.

[image]

**This is my current code:**

```css
header {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
    height: 79px;
}

header img {
    padding: 30px 50px 30px 50px;
}

nav {
    display: flex;
    padding: 0 25px;
    gap: 68px;
}

nav a {
    display: inline-block;
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    gap: 68px;
    margin-top: 9px;
    border-block-start: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

nav a:hover {
    color: var(--main-color);
    border-block-start: 2px solid var(--main-color);
}
```

```html
<header>
            <img src="images/logo/logo.png" alt="Logo">
                <nav>
                    <a href="">Hébergements</a>
                    <a href="">Activités</a>
                </nav>
        </header>
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `padding-top: 9px;` instead in `nav a`.

Then remove the default margin of `body`.

```css
body {
  margin-top: 0;
}

 :root {
  --main-color: blue;
}

header {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 79px;
}

header img {
  padding: 30px 50px 30px 50px;
}

nav {
  display: flex;
  padding: 0 25px;
  gap: 68px;
}

nav a {
  display: inline-block;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  gap: 68px;
  padding-top: 9px;
  border-block-start: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

nav a:hover {
  color: var(--main-color);
  border-block-start: 2px solid var(--main-color);
}
```

```html
<header>
  <img src="images/logo/logo.png" alt="Logo">
  <nav>
    <a href="">Hébergements</a>
    <a href="">Activités</a>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you so much! body didn't have a margin in the CSS file and I couldn't find where it was added, but while inspecting the page I noticed that it had 8px all around it, so I just manually added margin-top: 0; to it. Thanks again!